# Как считать объекты в вектор?

Tags: c++, vector, вектор

у меня задание. необходимо записать в объекты информацию и запихнуть в файл. а затем вытащить оттуда их и поместить в контейнер(я выбрала вектор, но если вы считаете что лист лучше я приму к сведению)
функция по записи:

```
const char *FName="teacher_file";

int save(int k)
{
        int key;
        char fio[100];
        int c;

        ofstream fout(FName,ios::binary|ios::app);
        for(int i=1; i<=k; i++)
        {

        cout<<"Введите ФИО: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(fio, 100);
        cout<<"Введите ключ: ";
        cin>>key;
        cout<<"Введите класс: ";
        cin>>c;
        Teacher s(key, fio, c);
        fout.write((char*)&s, sizeof(Teacher)); 
        }
        fout.close();
}
```

и функция read:

```
void read (int k)
{
    ifstream fout(FName, ios::binary|ios::in);
    Teacher S;
    vector<Teacher> teachers;
    while (!fout.eof())
    for(int i=1; i<=k; i++)
    {
    fout.read ((char*)&S, sizeof(Teacher));
    if(fout.eof()) break;
    teachers.push_back(S);
    for(int i = 0; i < teachers.size(); i++)
        cout << teachers[i] << ' ';//[Error] cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
    }
    fout.close();
}
```

в комментарии я привела ошибку из-за которой он этот вектор выводить не хочет.
была еще идея создать отдельный класс где будет поле vector teachers. это вроде глобальнее, но программа просто не видит этот вектор хоть я и подключила хедер. 
Вопросы: что за ошибку мне выдают, надо ли создавать отдельный класс для контейнера, как это исправить

Comment: Ну все, к `while (!fout.eof())` добавилось новое - бездумное `cin.ignore();`... Птенцы гнезда ЕГЭшного стали преподавателями... :(

Comment: По делу: где класс `Teacher`? О чем можно говорить без главного? Все равно что прийти к доктору и жаловаться на боль в ногах, но при этом давать посмотреть только на носочки...

Comment: Почитайте [тут](https://ravesli.com/urok-133-peregruzka-operatorov-vvoda-i-vyvoda/)